# How can i generate 8 circle Avatar widgets using grideview.bulder

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, generator

**flutter dart**

i am trying to generate 8 circle Avatar widgets using grideview.bulder then fetch them as a list into that grideview.bulder ..

i have done this , sorry i still Beginner

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Kkk extends StatefulWidget {
  const Kkk({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _KkkState createState() => _KkkState();
}

class _KkkState extends State<Kkk> {
  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(

        itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
        gridDelegate: null,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20),
            itemCount: 8,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
              return CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade800,
  child: const Text('YourText'),
);
            }),
```

you can create a list of items and use index to reach them for the string input for Text widget.Also, feel free to change grid delegate parameters to have various aspect ratios.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use index in the same you example which i need to make every image has index

Comment: in `itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {` line, `index` shows the index of each item in grid view, so let consider that you have a list named `testList`, then you can access to each element of this list as `testList[index]`.